# Printing issues on 14.04 LTS

Tags: printing, hplip

I have an HP Deskjet 2542. the printer is fine but the HPLIP program always delays me when I try to scan or print. I spend so much time going through menus trying to print or scan a document. It sometimes show that my printer is connected and other times does not. What could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall hplip and try disconnect and reconnect printer, it will find out the printer and you would be able to do your work, hplip sometimes works but sometimes it is better without hplip, i'm saying this on my personal experience. i have used several hp printers with linux, they all work . hp is best for linux.

Comment: thanks, how do you use your printers without the program? I thought that was the only way. Uninstalling it and reinstalling will take forever. I can't do that everytime.